# gridworld help-moving critters to open spot

Tags: java, bluej, gridworld

Alright so I have a project due for computer science, and I need help with grid world. I have the code written so I can click on a critter, but I want to click on the critter once, then click on an open spot on the grid to move the critter to. But it doesn't work. I need to get this working, and I don't know whats wrong with my code. Take a look. thanks for all your help

```
Actor t;

public boolean locationClicked(Location loc)
{
    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    t = gr.get(loc);
    Actor j;
    //Location second;
    if (t != null) 
    { 
        setMessage("Click on " + t);
        numOfClicks++;
        if(t instanceof BlackCheckers || t instanceof RedCheckers)
        {

            if(numOfClicks==0)
            {
                secondClick(second);
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {            

        setMessage("Click on nothing");

    }      
    return true;   
}
Location second;
public void secondClick(Location second)
{
    this.second=second;
    Grid<Actor> op=getGrid();
    Actor te=op.get(second);
    if(te==null)
    {
        t.moveTo(second);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Also can you please format the top part of your code (put in 4 spaces next to `Actor`)?

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond what I know about Gridworld, but I found something that might help.

---

### **How You Can Intercept Mouse Clicks and Keystrokes**

The `World` class has student-friendly mechanisms for intercepting mouse clicks and keystrokes. No knowledge of AWT events is required.

When the user clicks on a grid location, the `locationClicked` method of the `World` is called. By default, that method returns `false`, which tells the framework to initiate the default action, namely to move the selection square and to show the constructor or method menu.

To intercept the mouse click, override the `locationClicked` method. Carry out any desired action and return `true`. The grid location on which the user clicked is passed as a parameter. Typical actions include flipping tiles, populating empty locations, and so on.

Sometimes, you need to ask the user for additional information after the mouse click. The easiest method is to use a `JOptionPane`.

Let’s consider a common situation. In a game, a user selects a piece. You want to ask where the user wants to move the piece. You can wait for another mouse click. That means,
your `locationClicked` method needs to keep track of the click state (piece selection vs. target selection). Or you can enumerate all legal targets and call `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog.`

When the user hits a key, the `keyPressed` method of the `World` is called. By default, that method returns `false`, which tells the framework to initiate the default key action. If the user hit a cursor key, the selection square is moved. If the user hit the Enter key, the constructor or method menu is shown. All other keys are ignored.

To intercept the keystroke, override the `keyPressed` method. The method receives the current location and the keystroke string, encoded in the same format that is used by the `java.awt.KeyStroke` class. Example keystroke strings are "INSERT" or "alt shift X". Your `keyPressed` method should check the keystroke string. If the string matches a keystroke that you want to intercept, carry out any desired action and return `true`. Return `false` for all other keystrokes. It is a good idea to return `false` for the cursor keys and the Enter key. Otherwise, the standard actions are disabled for your world.

---

[Source (pg 16)](http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/ap-sf-computer-science-gridworld.pdf)